# C++ Iterator in my class not taking in my struct as a type

Tags: c++, class, vector, iterator

I have a class called MyHashMap and I want to implement an iterator but for some reason I can't. I have a vector that takes in a private struct as a type just fine but when I try to define it with an iterator in my public sector, it's saying that HashEntry is not declared. Here's my class.

```
template<typename KeyType, typename ObjectType>
class MyHashMap 
{
  public:

/***********ITERATOR FUNCTIONS****************/

    typedef typename std::vector<HashEntry>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename std::vector<HashEntry>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator begin() { return array.begin(); }

    const_iterator begin() const { return array.begin(); }

    iterator end() { return array.end(); }

    const_iterator end() const { return array.end(); }

  private:
    struct HashEntry
    {
        KeyType     element;
        ObjectType  mapped;
        EntryType   info;

        HashEntry(  const KeyType & e = KeyType{ }, 
                    const ObjectType & m = ObjectType{ }, 
                    EntryType i = EMPTY )
                    : element{ e }, mapped{ m }, info{ i } { }

        HashEntry(  KeyType && e, 
                    ObjectType && m, 
                    EntryType i = EMPTY )
                    : element{ std::move( e ) }, mapped{ std::move( m ) }, info{ i } { }
    };

    vector<HashEntry> array;
};
```

I'm getting these as errors

```
error: ‘HashEntry’ was not declared in this scope
    typedef typename std::vector<HashEntry>::iterator iterator;
                             ^
error: template argument 1 is invalid
    typedef typename std::vector<HashEntry>::iterator iterator;
                                      ^
error: template argument 2 is invalid
error: ‘HashEntry’ was not declared in this scope
     typedef typename std::vector<HashEntry>::const_iterator const_iterator;
                              ^
error: template argument 1 is invalid
     typedef typename std::vector<HashEntry>::const_iterator const_iterator;
                                       ^
error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Any ideas what's wrong? I'm fairly sure the answer is simple but I just can't figure it out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you declared `HashEntry` **after** you used it as template parameter.

It should be this way:

```
template<typename KeyType, typename ObjectType>
class MyHashMap 
{
  private:
    struct HashEntry
    {
        KeyType     element;
        ObjectType  mapped;
        EntryType   info;

        HashEntry(  const KeyType & e = KeyType{ }, 
                    const ObjectType & m = ObjectType{ }, 
                    EntryType i = EMPTY )
                    : element{ e }, mapped{ m }, info{ i } { }

        HashEntry(  KeyType && e, 
                    ObjectType && m, 
                    EntryType i = EMPTY )
                    : element{ std::move( e ) }, mapped{ std::move( m ) }, info{ i } { }
    };

    vector<HashEntry> array;

  public:
    /***********ITERATOR FUNCTIONS****************/

    //Now you can use 'HashEntry' as it is visible now:

    typedef typename std::vector<HashEntry>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename std::vector<HashEntry>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator begin() { return array.begin(); }

    const_iterator begin() const { return array.begin(); }

    iterator end() { return array.end(); }

    const_iterator end() const { return array.end(); }
};
```

**EDIT**

I think forward declaration should be enough here, because when `MyHashMap` is instantiated, `HashEntry` is already defined.

But I think, that you should stick to one, consistent order of declaring things inside classes (especially templated ones). 
I always do this as follows:

For example, this is a snippet from one of my custom containers:
- internal types and structs
- base iterators
- public typedefs
- members
- public interface
Then, everything is always at the right place.

```
template <class T>
class SortedArray
{
protected:
    class Block
    {
      //...
    };

    class InternalCompare
    {
      //...
    };

    template <IteratorType Iter_type>
    class IteratorBase
    {
      //...
    };

    template <IteratorType Iter_type>
    class InternalIterator : public IteratorBase<Iter_type>
    {
      //...
    };

    template <IteratorType Iter_type>
    class InternalReverseIterator : public IteratorBase<Iter_type>
    {
      //...
    };

public:
    typedef SortedArray<T> MyType;

    typedef InternalIterator<IteratorType::Non_Const>           Iterator;
    typedef InternalIterator<IteratorType::Const>               ConstIterator;
    typedef InternalReverseIterator<IteratorType::Non_Const>    ReverseIterator;
    typedef InternalReverseIterator<IteratorType::Const>        ConstReverseIterator;


protected:
    DynamicBuffer<Block>    _blocks;
    Size_t                  _blocks_num;
    Size_t                  _elements_num;
    Block*                  _first_block;
    Block*                  _last_block;

public:
    SortedArray()
    {
      //...
    };

    //etc.
};
```

But that is just an example.

**EDIT 2**

An alternative solution to the posted one is to only forward-declare `HashEntry`. This will only modify your original code with one additional line of code:

```
//This is your original code.
template<typename KeyType, typename ObjectType>
class MyHashMap 
{
private:
    struct HashEntry; //This forward declaration is sufficient for everything to work properly.

public:
    /***********ITERATOR FUNCTIONS****************/
    typedef typename std::vector<HashEntry>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename std::vector<HashEntry>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator begin() { return array.begin(); }

    const_iterator begin() const { return array.begin(); }

    iterator end() { return array.end(); }

    const_iterator end() const { return array.end(); }

private:
    struct HashEntry
    {
        KeyType     element;
        ObjectType  mapped;
        EntryType   info;

        HashEntry(  const KeyType & e = KeyType{ }, 
                    const ObjectType & m = ObjectType{ }, 
                    EntryType i = EMPTY )
                    : element{ e }, mapped{ m }, info{ i } { }

        HashEntry(  KeyType && e, 
                    ObjectType && m, 
                    EntryType i = EMPTY )
                    : element{ std::move( e ) }, mapped{ std::move( m ) }, info{ i } { }
    };

    vector<HashEntry> array;
};
```

Comment: I think it's safe here to forward declare it if you want, as you just define a type, and at usage time `HashEntry` will be fully defined.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I wasn't aware the placement mattered.

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, forward declaration would be sufficient here. I updated my answer with that note and also added small example of ordering scheme I personally use.

Comment: @Mateusz Grzejek, I'm a little confuse, what am I suppose to forward declare? My HashEntry or my iterator? And what's the syntax for forward declaration of a struct? Sorry this is relatively new to me. I am looking at your example and I am having trouble understanding what's going on.

Comment: Ok, from my understanding, I have to have my HashEntry in a protected sector before my public. I think I get it now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: See updated answer. You can leave everything as it was before. All you need to do is to add single line of code. In some cases (when you can't or don't want to reorder things inside a class) this is the best (and fastest) solution. However, I prefer to avoid unnecessary forward-declarations, because in large projects it makes code maintenance more difficult.